# Converted javascript class to typescript class: some properties are not visible

Tags: typescript

I have a javascript class in a project which I want to convert to typescript:

```
class PricePlan {

    constructor(name, supplier, unitRate, peakTimeMultipliers) {
        this.name = name
        this.supplier = supplier
        this.unitRate = unitRate
        this.peakTimeMultipliers = peakTimeMultipliers
    }

    getPrice(dateTime) {
        let peakMultiplier = this.peakTimeMultipliers.find(multiplier => {
            return multiplier.day === dateTime.getDay()
        });
        return peakMultiplier ? peakMultiplier.multiplier : this.unitRate;
    }
}

PricePlan.DayOfWeek = Object.freeze({
    Sunday:0,
    Monday:1,
    Tuesday:2,
    Wednesday:3,
    Thursday:4,
    Friday:5,
    Saturday:6
})

PricePlan.PeakTimeMultiplier = class {
    constructor(dayOfWeek, multiplier) {
        this.day = dayOfWeek
        this.multiplier = multiplier
    }
}

module.exports = PricePlan
```

I have changed the class to be a typescript class like this:

```
export class PricePlan {
    private name;
    private supplier;
    private unitRate;
    private peakTimeMultipliers

    constructor(name, supplier, unitRate, peakTimeMultipliers = false) {
        this.name = name
        this.supplier = supplier
        this.unitRate = unitRate
        this.peakTimeMultipliers = peakTimeMultipliers
    }

    getPrice(dateTime) {
        let peakMultiplier = this.peakTimeMultipliers.find(multiplier => {
            return multiplier.day === dateTime.getDay()
        });
        return peakMultiplier ? peakMultiplier.multiplier : this.unitRate;
    }

    DayOfWeek = {
        Sunday: 0,
        Monday: 1,
        Tuesday: 2,
        Wednesday: 3,
        Thursday: 4,
        Friday: 5,
        Saturday: 6
    }

    PeakTimeMultiplier = class {
        private day
        private multiplier

        constructor(dayOfWeek, multiplier) {
            this.day = dayOfWeek
            this.multiplier = multiplier
        }
    }
}
```

Now there's no compiler error, but the class gets called like this in a test:

```
let peakTimeMultiplier = new PricePlan.PeakTimeMultiplier(PricePlan.DayOfWeek.Wednesday, 10)
```

Here I have two errors:

- Property 'PeakTimeMultiplier' does not exist on type 'typeof PricePlan'
- Property 'DayOfWeek' does not exist on type 'typeof PricePlan'

Those are the properties which I moved inside the class. How can I make them visible?

Comment: They need to be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to fix your build is to just declare `DayOfWeek` and `PeakTimeMultiplier` as `static` . Sometimes is cleaner to refactor those into a namespace like this:

```
export class PricePlan {
    private name;
    private supplier;
    private unitRate;
    private peakTimeMultipliers

    constructor(name, supplier, unitRate, peakTimeMultipliers = false) {
        this.name = name
        this.supplier = supplier
        this.unitRate = unitRate
        this.peakTimeMultipliers = peakTimeMultipliers
    }

    getPrice(dateTime) {
        let peakMultiplier = this.peakTimeMultipliers.find(multiplier => {
            return multiplier.day === dateTime.getDay()
        });
        return peakMultiplier ? peakMultiplier.multiplier : this.unitRate;
    }  
}

export namespace PricePlan {
  export const enum DayOfWeek {
        Sunday,
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday
    }

    export class PeakTimeMultiplier {
        private day
        private multiplier

        constructor(dayOfWeek, multiplier) {
            this.day = dayOfWeek
            this.multiplier = multiplier
        }
    }
}
```

See that also `DayOfWeek` is declared as an `enum`